# Query in Django to sort in one table based on result of another table

Tags: python, django

I have two models
listing model is:

```
class listing(models.Model):
    productTitle= models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    productPrice = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.productTitle
```

my watchlist model is:

```
    item = models.ForeignKey(listing, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    watchlist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

In my index.html
I want to show the list item if watchlist attribute is False.

Now, my views.py for index.html is as follows:

```
def index(request):
    if request.user != "AnonymousUser":
        items= listing.objects.exclude(id=watchlist.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    else:
        items = watchlist.objects.all()
    context = {'items':items}
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", context)
```

I couldn't filter the items on listing models based on the result of watchlist model i.e if watchlist=True then I do not want to render items on index.html. Because, I want to render watchlist items in separate pages.
How to query in django if there are two models used?

Answer (score 0):

You could have probably do something like this

```
watch_list = watchlist.objects.filter(wishlist=False, user=request.user.id).values('item')
```

Then if you want to fetch items, you do like this

```
items = listing.objects.filter(id__in=watch_list)
```

Comment: Thanks..however, If one user submit to watchlist, that item is not listed for next user in listing.

Comment: Ok, then the first query should be `watch_list = watchlist.objects.filter(wishlist=False).values('item')`

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Q    
items = listing.objects.filter(watchlist__isnull=True) | listing.objects.filter(Q(watchlist__user=request.user) & Q(watchlist__watchlist=False))
```

If my understanding is correct you need to list items which are not in watchlist table too. You could use backwards relation in query. **watchlist__isnull=True** is for listing the entries not in watchlist table. The second part **listing.objects.filter(Q(watchlist__user=request.user) & Q(watchlist__watchlist=False)** is the watchlist filter